1-hour or so long TV Episode about a being in a volcano
I saw this on T.V. about four years ago, but I'm sure it was first aired much, much earlier since the video looked very old.

There were these two people, whose names I cannot remember: A man and a woman.
They were either CIA or FBI agents.
The woman was somewhat short and had either blonde or brunette hair.
The man was tall and wore a suit, and most of the time a blue shirt.
They were out near some volcano, investigating what seemed to be something alive in there.
It was later found that there was some contagion in the area, and the episode ends with some CDC officers coming in and sealing it.

I strongly suspect this is an episode from the X-Files.

This might be from The X-Files, season 2, episode 9: "Firewalker" 
IMDB
Plot-Wikipedia :

Dr. Adam Pierce, a scientist at the California Institute of Technology
  in Pasadena, intercepts a visual transmission from Firewalker, a
  mobile robot sent by a volcanic research project on Mount Avalon near
  Bend, Oregon. Firewalker is broadcasting from inside a volcanic cave,
  where Pierce glimpses the dead body of the chief seismologist, Phil
  Erickson. He also sees a shadow moving in the cave, an impossibility
  due to the extremely high temperatures. Firewalker's camera is then
  destroyed, ending the transmission.
Pierce goes to Fox Mulder (David Duchovny) and Dana Scully (Gillian
  Anderson), showing them a TV interview of the project's leader, Daniel
  Trepkos (Bradley Whitford); Pierce was with the project until he and
  Trepkos had a falling out. Mulder is reluctant to let Scully come
  along because of her recent abduction; Scully, however, insists that
  she is ready. Upon arriving at Mount Avalon, Pierce goes out in the
  woods to inspect the project's equipment while the agents search the
  laboratory. They discover the seemingly traumatized team: robotics
  engineer Jason Ludwig (Leland Orser), systems analyst Peter Tanaka
  (Hiro Kanagawa), and graduate student Jessie O'Neil (Shawnee Smith).
  They claim that Trepkos destroyed their lab and disappeared after
  Firewalker's first descent. Meanwhile, outside, Trepkos strangles
  Pierce.
After the team finds and stores Pierce's body, Mulder reviews Trepkos'
  fragmented notes. He finds references to a new silicon-based organism
  existing inside Mount Avalon; Scully, however, doubts his conclusions
  because of his mental state. Tanaka breaks into convulsions and
  displays a high fever, but refuses any help from Mulder or Scully.
  When he is put on a stretcher for a medivac pickup, Mulder notices a
  throbbing bulge in his neck. Tanaka flees into the woods and dies when
  a tentacle bursts out of his throat. An autopsy by Scully finds sand
  in his lungs, indicating the existence of a silicon-based spore; she
  theorizes that when exposed, the spore infects the nearest hosts or
  otherwise dies. Mulder contacts the CDC to have them quarantine the
  site.
Mulder and Ludwig venture into the volcanic caves to find Trepkos.
  When they find Firewalker, Trepkos shoots Ludwig in the back with a
  flare gun, killing him. He then burns Ludwig's body, as he was
  infected with the spore as well. Trepkos tells Mulder that after
  Firewalker returned from its first descent, Erickson pulverized a rock
  in one of its samples, resulting in his death and the infection of all
  the scientists immediately surrounding him. Trepkos says that the
  spore is parasitic in nature, making its hosts pass itself on to
  others. Meanwhile, in the lab, an infected O'Neil handcuffs herself to
  Scully to expose her to the spore, forcing Scully to use a hammer to
  split the chains but to no avail, so she instead protects herself by
  throwing O'Neil into a sealed chamber and closing the door. A
  protrusion then bursts out of O'Neil's throat, killing her without
  spreading the spore to Scully.
Mulder and Trepkos arrive on the scene. Mulder radios the evacuation
  team but—knowing that Trepkos will refuse to go—reports that only he
  and Scully have survived the ordeal. The agents enter a month-long
  quarantine while the Chemical Corps confiscates the lab and cordons
  off Mount Avalon. Firewalker is salvaged, but is too damaged to yield
  sufficient data. Trepkos and O'Neil are officially unaccounted for and
  presumed dead; Trepkos is last seen carrying O'Neil's body as he
  disappears into the volcano.

Promo Spot

I think full plot was not required, you could have highlighted essential parts or given your own short synopses
